# POS EMV Card PIN Change

Tags: emv, pos

I would like to know if there is a possibility of changing the PIN of an EMV card using POS devices equipped with an IC Reader. Or if that functionality is reserved for ATMs only.

If its possible through POS Devices, what series of commands does one need to issue to make the PIN change.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

EMV Offline PIN change is performed by issuer script that is sent together with response to authorization request. It does not matter if device is POS or ATM. It technically works the same and issuer scripts are guaranteed (up to 127 bytes) to be transferred through any authorization protocol.

ATMs have additional requirements from payment schemes, so PIN Change and PIN unblock transaction support are obligatory. With POS, there is no direct requirement to be able to initiate such transactions, but if it is performed over some other channel (IVR, online, etc), issuer scripts can transfer the PIN to the card on the next online transaction regardless if card is used on ATM or POS.

No special commands are there for PIN change, the transaction will require entering both old and new PIN, send them in encrypted PIN Blocks and the response shall contain issuer script that will be sent by EMV kernel to the card (without modification or interpretation by the device) as any other issuer script.

Side note - bigger issuer scripts are not common and handled in devices that are connected through On-us interfaces with issuer banks. For large issuer scripts, devices that can avoid card removal during the process are preferred (mostly bank owned ATMs with motorized readers).

Answer (score 1):

EMV cards supported two types of pin concept -

1) **Offline pin**
2) **Online pin**.

If card supported offline pin i.e. pin is **stored** in the card itself and if it need to change then issuer script will be executed.

**Issuer script** is a set of commands that runs between POS and EMV card and change the offline pin.

If card supported online pin i.e. pin is **not inside** the card, saved at somewhere. For changing this pin, no need to present card at POS, can change by any mode ATM, Internet Banking etc.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry my response might be late but i hope it helps. This entirely depends on the functions supported by your terminal acquire.

For offline pin change for instance;
If the function is supported by your aquirer/issuer, the user can initiate a pin change on the terminal itself.
After that, the very first transaction on the card will return an issuer script data in the tag "72" to communicate with the pin change function on the card run before the second generate Account Cryptogram. If the response to the issuer script command returns 9000, the proccess completes to second generate AC command, ortherwise the Terminal runs a trasuction reversal process hence the pin reset failed.

It is a long broad respose but i hope it covers the idea.

Comment: For tag 72, scripts will be processed after second GEN AC. To process it before second GEN AC, it has to be tag 71.

Answer (score -1):

As long as the POS has IC reader, you can read IC card based getProcessing options and static data for authentication, the answer is YES.

Whether the PIN is stored on the card in OWNERPIN variable or at the Bank(the issuer) is a function of the card usage profile defined by the issuer. Your terminal application can communicate the PIN to the card through various processing steps.